# XAMPP in Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, xampp, virtualhost

I am a newbie to Ubuntu and XAMPP (XAMPP-Linux).  I installed Ubuntu first and Apache, MySQL and PHP with that.  Then I installed XAMPP.  I am able to get to `/home/username/directory1`.  Then I am able to see an `index.html` file in directory1 and a `test.php` file in directory1.

However, I changed httpd.conf to take it to `/home/username/directory2`(in directory 2 I have `test.php`).

I am able to see `phpinfo()` page, which states that I am using directory1. 
Please help me understand it.  At the moment I get this blindly. Also I am unable to get to XAMPP using localhost/xampp.

Could this be duplication due to installing Ubuntu + Apache,MySQL and PHP first?

Answer (score 0):

Xampp is not packaged with Ubuntu. You can use it but if you are a newbie you might want to stick to the standard and use LAMP instead (which is basically the same but packaged for Ubuntu). If you have a clean system it might indeed be better to just start over and stick to the Ubuntu packaging.

Having said that, you state that you changed httpd.conf, this is not the standard Ubuntu config file for Apache. The standard for Ubuntu get its config from:

> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

within this file you can enable httpd.conf, thought the standard would be to edit the files in site-available and link them to sites-enabled.

Answer (score -1):

For sure you do no have to install apache, mysql, php and then XAMPP. This is a duplicate install. XAMPP is a pre-configured set mainly of this 3 pieces. Lamp it's not my area. 
If you are new to Linux, I recommend to start again with a fresh OS. Trying to fix everything may lead to hours of work and then hate linux. Then choose how to install lamp, just installing one by one piece or XAMPP.